# Usb WiFi Dongle RaspberryPi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, dongle

I want to set raspberrypi network ssid and password over Android application. My problem is how can I do. I know command line method or raspi wifi settings in desktop. I just want to do usb wifi dongle setting over Android app.

Comment: Your question is too much ambiguous. Plz edit and clarify it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ssh applications on android ? You can remote access Rpi if both your phone and Rpi are on the same network. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the configurations using command line. hope you are using Linux.

Open the wpa-supplicant configuration file in nano:

```
network={
    ssid="The_ESSID_from_earlier"
    psk="Your_wifi_password"
}
```

Now save the file by pressing Ctrl+X then Y, then finally press Enter.

At this point, wpa-supplicant will normally notice a change has occurred within a few seconds, and it will try and connect to the network.

And if not

sudo ifdown wlan0 and sudo ifup wlan0, or reboot your Raspberry Pi with sudo reboot.